# RichTextbox for o365 sharepoint provider hosted app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, richtextbox, sharepoint-online, csom, provider-hosted

Can you please tell me which richtexeditor works well on sharepoint provider hosted app for o365.

I am already using CkEditor, but when I upload the app it is not working properly, may be I do some mistake, but problem is with same configurations it is working fine when I run the app through localhost.

please give me your suggestions.

B.R

Comment: Hi Wasif,
You can try SharePoint RTE JQuery plugin,
http://makingthings.work/sharepoint-rte-jquery-plugin/

Comment: Thanks Jatin, I was doing wrong referencing in BundleConfig file. Now it is working fine. Thanks for your suggestion.